# How to add custom field in create user form in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

Can any one help me with adding custom field in create user page in alfresco,
I tried adding custom field in profile by referring 
http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2012/02/27/1555

but how to do it for create user page in admin console?

i had gone through the users.js and edited with the new field created by referring the above link. but still im not able to save the field for newly created users and while updating user from admin console.

Anyone, Kindly help me in this regard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are many changes required in different file.
Take the help of this link [Custom Field in User Profile](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/171497-custom-fields-in-user-profile). May be you will get some idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

Actually im looking to use the custom field in create user page which is created in profile page by referring the link https://github.com/sujaypillai/someco-people